# Ember V1.0.0-pre.2: how to get query string parameters

Tags: ember.js

Is it at all possible to get the query string parameters in pre2?

e.g., we would like to transition to a route like so: `#/customer/CN-001` where `CN-001` would match some parameter along the lines of `/customer/:customernumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

Routers:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    ApplicationController: Ember.ObjectController.extend(),
    CustomerController: Ember.ObjectController.extend(),
    Router: Ember.Router.extend({
        root: Ember.Route.extend({                        
            index: Em.Route.extend({    
                route: '/',
                connectOutlets: function(router) {
                    router.route('/customer/CN-001');
                }
            }),
            customer: Em.Route.extend({            
                route: '/customer/:customernumber',
                connectOutlets: function(router, customer) {                    
                    router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet('customer', customer);                    
                },
                serialize:  function(router, context){
                    return { id: context.number };
                },
                deserialize: function(router, params) {
                    return Ember.Object.create({ number: params.customernumber });
                }
            })            
        })
    })
});

App.CustomerView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'customer'
})
```

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">    
    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="customer">
  <h2>Customer</h2>  
    {{number}}
</script>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/dGBet/) is a jsfiddle showing this working.
I hope it help.

Comment: I don't quite get what the serialize is doing but I guess it is OK :) --- we'll be upgrading our Ember soon but thanks for your effort!